# Show that the graph of a function has measure zero (Stein & Shakarchi, Analysis III, Exercise 2.7)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

In the book "Real Analysis III" by Stein and Shakarchi, on page 91, the problem 7 of the chapter 2 asks:

> Let $\Gamma\subset\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}$, $\Gamma=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R} : y = f(x)\}$, and assume $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Show that $\Gamma$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$, and $m(\Gamma)=0$.

I am simply wondering if my proof is correct, as every solution I find online is way more complicated. It goes like this:

Define the new function $F:\mathbb{R}^{d+1}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $F(x,y)=f(x)$. The Corollary 3.7 in the book states precisely that since $f$ is measurable, the new function $F$ is also measurable on $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$. Therefore, the set $\Gamma = \{F\leq 0\}\cap \{F\geq 0\}$ is measurable, as the intersection of two measurable sets. Now, to compute $m(\Gamma)$, notice that
$$ m(\Gamma) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d+1}} 1_{\Gamma}(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_\Gamma(x,y)\,dy\,dx$$ by Fubini's theorem. But when $x$ is fixed, $1_\Gamma(x,y)=1_{\{f(x)\}}(y)$, so
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_\Gamma(x,y)\,dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{\{f(x)\}}(y)\,dy = m(\{f(x)\})=0$$
and so
$$m(\Gamma) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} 0\,dx = 0.$$

As I asked at the beginning, is my reasonning correct?